# Find a word in a string

Tags: php, string

I am trying to make this work.  Please help

```
function rsfp_onSelectDate(day)
{
if(day strpos('Sunday') !== false));
{
    alert("We are Closed on Sunday");
    return false;
}
else return true;
}
```

Comment: don't make up your own syntax. Read PHP docs !

Comment: "I am not able to rightly apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question." 
 -- Charles Babbage (1791-1871)

Comment: }else { return true; }

Comment: This looks more like JavaScript than PHP.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a mix of JavaScript and PHP. No use of `$` before variable names means it's not PHP, `alert` is a JS function, but `strpos` and its usage is very PHP.

Comment: You are totally right! What a mess :) too many beers before sitting down at the computer. It is JavaScript and when I was writing it I don't know what I was thinking.  The original code is this: 
function rsfp_onSelectDate(param1)
{
 if(param1 == "31.12.2010") 
 {
  alert("We are closed on Sunday");
  return false;
 }
 else return true;
}
and I needed it to work based on day of the week

Answer (score 4):

```
day strpos('Sunday')
```

doesn't look valid to me, you should try:

```
strpos($day, 'Sunday')
```

instead. From the [online docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> **`int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`**
>
> - Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

---

As, as some witty commenter has remarked, you shouldn't just expect to make up syntax and expect it to work. This code seems to be some strange hybrid of PHP and JavaScript. JS would use `indexOf` rather than `strpos` but PHP has no built-in `alert` function as JS does. In addition, your `day` variable would be `$day` in PHP.

Comment: also, `alert()` is a JS function